# Get the value of the lowest array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which returns this:

```
    Array (
            [122] => value
            [43] => value1
            [654645] => value2
            [34634] => value3
            [3] => value4  // I want this
            [550] => value5
    )
```

How can I return `value4` from the lowest key `[3]`, I have read http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php and attempted some of the sort by key examples with no luck.

Comment: Either get the keys in an array with `array_keys()` and get the lowest key with `min()` to then access the element OR sort the array with `ksort()` and access the first array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one-liner:

```
echo $array[min(array_keys($array))];
```

Explanation:

- `array_keys($array)` gets keys of your source array as new array, ie. `[122, 43, 654645, /*etc*/]`
- `min()` gets the lowest value of this array - `3`
- passing lowest value `3` as index will give your the value of a source array

Comment: Brilliant - can you just explain what that is doing briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:-

```
echo min(array_keys($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also helpful to you...

`echo min(array_keys($arr));`

Answer (score -1):

to get the minimum array count

```
array_search(min($array), $array);
```

to get the value of minimum array

```
echo $array[array_search(min($array), $array)];
```